# Insert multiple elements in .bindPopup in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a function which extracts multiple elements from JSON datatype. I try to bind now multiple elements from my function in my popup divided by paragraphs, but I'm not able to set multiple variables in the popup. How can integrate multiple elements? I tried `paste()` or `&` but it won't work.

```
function getUsers() {
        $.getJSON("getData.php", function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var location    = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng);
        var species     = data[i].species;
        var diameter    = data[i].average_diameter;
        var quality     = data[i].quality;
        var damage      = data[i].damage;
        var notes       = data[i].additional_information;
        var marker      = L.marker([data[i].lat, data[i].lng], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
                            marker.bindPopup(diameter);
                            
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
marker.bindPopup(diameter + "|" + quality);
// or
marker.bindPopup(`${diameter} | ${quality}`);
```